# eth_getStorageAt params names

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I am calling geth rpc method **eth_getStorageAt** using json-rpc-cpp libarary. I need to know the parameters' names for the method. I can find parameters' names for **eth_sendTransaction** from [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendtransaction), which includes "from", "to" and so on. My questions is where to find the similiar ones for **eth_getStorageAt**, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getstorageat).

Have a look at the examples in that link. You don't need to create an object that includes the keys of the parameters' names.

```
eth_getStorageAt

Returns the value from a storage position at a given address.

Parameters
 * DATA, 20 Bytes - address of the storage.
 * QUANTITY - integer of the position in the storage.
 * QUANTITY|TAG - integer block number, or the string "latest", "earliest" or "pending", see the default block parameter

Returns

DATA - the value at this storage position.
```